# Can a single $rootScope.$broadcast call multiple $scope.$on?

Tags: angularjs

I have a service call which when succeeds provide the data to multiple controllers at the same time. I am $broadcasting the same to multiple $on. I am getting them in one of the $on but not the others. Is $broadcast created in such a manner that it will transmit the same only to the first $on it finds?

Comment: perhaps post a snippet of code so we can help you out why your other "$ons" are not receiving the broadcast

Comment: Sounds like you are expecting inactive controllers to receive events. That is not the case, however all active listeners will receive same event. Alternatively you may be broadcasting when you need to be emitting depending on which scope you are using. Show us your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can a single $rootScope.$broadcast call multiple $scope.$on?

Based on the documentation for [$broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast), yes.